# got positional argument error when using decorator in python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have defined a decorator function in python, but I get positional argument error when using it. This is my code:

```
def my_upper_case(func):

    def wrapper():
        return func().upper()

    return wrapper


@my_upper_case
def print_name(name):
    return name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(print_name("zeinab"))
```

Returned error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(print_name("zeinab"))
TypeError: wrapper() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I tried running the code with both python 2.7 and python 3.6. Both returned exact error.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, your wrapper function doesn't accept any arguments. It needs to accept the same args as the function it is wrapping.

```
def wrapper(arg):
    return func(arg).upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

`wrapper` wraps the function, meaning it will 'act in its place'.

Therefore, if you call `print_name("zeinab")`, the wrapper will be called instead with `wrapper("zeinab")`.

`wrapper` doesn't accept the `"zeinab"` argument, because you didn't give it any parameters.

```py
def my_upper_case(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs).upper()

    return wrapper


@my_upper_case
def print_name(name):
    return name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(print_name("zeinab"))
```